# Upgrade 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, do-release-upgrade

As I tried to upgrade Ubuntu 20.04.4 server to 22.04 but I got this message after do-release-upgrade.

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

I set Prompt=lts cause I want to upgrade to next LTS. But this setting does nothing at all. When I set Prompt=normal system will get upgraded to 21.10

Is there a way to do a direct upgrade to 22.04?

Comment: Upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 will not be ready until 22.04.1 comes out. This is to make sure the LTS to LTS is as stable as possible. This has always (AFAIK) been the case for LTS to LTS upgrades.